# Raspberry Pi 4 Network issues

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi4, wpa-supplicant

I'm a teacher in a school and I'm trying to allow my students to connect their Rpi robots to the school's wifi. The previous Rpi3s work on this network but the Rpi4s do not. They are running Linux 10 buster.

The wpa_supplicant file contains the following:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU

network={
  ssid="########"
  scan_ssid=1
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  eap=PEAP
  identity="######"
  password="#######"
  phase1="peaplabel=0"
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  priority=1
}
```

When I check the system logs, I get similar to the following:

````
dhcpcd: wlan0: connected to Access Point '###########'
kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 1280 Comm: wpa_supplicant Tainted: G   WC   5.10.103-v7l+ #1529
(warn_slowpath_fmt) from [<bf6f08b8>] (brcmf_cfg80211) [brcmfmac]
dhcpcd: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
dhcpcd: wlan0: carrier lost ```

Has anyone experienced this error and resolved it?
````

Answer (score 0):

Answer was given to me on the rasperrypi forum.

The solution is to add the following lines to /etc/dhcpcd.conf

interface wlan0
env ifwireless=1
env wpa_supplicant_driver=wext,n180211